# Connecting to remote postgres database using Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, postgresql, jdbc

This is my first time connecting to remote database using android studio.
Program logs : not-Connected.
I have used same function to connect in eclipse, but it doesn't work in AS.

```
static Connection connection = null;

public static void databaseConnect() {
        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:postgresql://ec2-52********amazonaws.com:5432/d3****hg";
        String username = "ve*****cgo";
        String password = "efc**********f16";

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password);
            Log.d("log", "databaseConnect: Connected");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("log", "databaseConnect: not-Connected");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have tried adding mssql-jdbc.jar to libs folder and adding android.premission.INTERNET to manifest, but I am obviously missing some steps. I couldn't find solution online so I am posting this question so somebody can hopefully help.

Comment: `Program logs : not-Connected` ok, but what is the stack trace ?

Comment: If you want to connect to a PostgreSQL database, why are you trying to use the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver? If you want to connect PostgreSQL, you should use the PostgreSQL JDBC driver. As an aside, you really should not use JDBC drivers from an Android application, it usually performs badly, but more to the point, recent versions of JDBC drivers don't always work on Android, because they use classes or features of Java that are not available on Android. Instead, use a web application to mediate between your Android application and the database.